# Hive custom XML input

Tags: xml, input, hadoop, format, hive

I have some issue with xml input for the hive table.
My hive version is 0.10
I created table by this statment:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE logAlert (storexml string) 
STORED AS 
  INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.XmlInputFormat' 
  OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

I don't have problem with table creation, but when i try get data from table, it provide this error:
SemanticException 1:14 Input format must implement InputFormat

I tried different ways which not work for me: 
1) use only mapred package;
2) i created class which extends TextInputFormat from mapred package;
3) use mahout example from 0.1 version.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: This looks like a version problem to me, make sure the XmlInputFormat version is matching up with what you are running against, it might be a different path

Comment: Heh, i updated hue to 0.10.1 version and it work fine)